# How to consolidate array with count of duplicate values

Tags: javascript, arrays, count

I have a nesting function that produces multiple arrays as it runs through its looping.
So I end up with a few lines of arrays, but want to make them a bit easier to read as they're to be used for a cutting list.

An example of an array might be:
280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280 - **Offcut:** 60
343,343,343,343,343,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280,280 - **Offcut:** 25

So I'm trying to write within the same function without calling another, that can count how many individual quantities of each length will fit within a given limit.

The way I'm printing these results is by changing the innerHTML of a cell.

```
document.getElementById("descOutput").innerHTML += "<br/><b>Result:</b>"+arr;
document.getElementById("descOutput").innerHTML += " - <b>Offcut:</b> "+off;
```

That way, after each loop that produces an answer that is under the limit, it writes it into the cell.
What I'm hoping to achieve is as below:

[280 x23] - Offcut: 60

[343 x5,280x17] - Offcut: 25

Can anybody help?

Comment: What do you mean by offcut? Can you should your actual JSON?

Comment: *"So I'm trying to write within the same function without calling another,..."* Don't see any code that resembles a function that handles arrays...Improve your question, read about [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl I've tried the solutions given in that question, it didn't work for what I want.

Comment: No reason it shouldn't work. Show us what you tried